# Replacement for Moto X 2nd gen (2014)

Tags: android, smartphones

SO, I really love my Moto X 2, and it still work very well, but it's starting to get a little old... the battery doesn't last as much as it did, and the 2GB of RAM is starting to get a little cramped. Also, as usual for Android phones, the software stopped being updated.

What I love about it:

- Always-on voice recognition (even with the screen turned off);
- The sensors in front that allow to turn the phone on using the Force;
- The light Android skin (no TouchWiz for me, thank you);
- The AMOLED screen;
- The small (relative to the current trend of 42" phones) size of 5.2".

Is there any current phone that have those features, but with larger RAM, preferably longer battery life, and size equal or smaller? If it can cost less than $400, even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all always-on voice recognition phones are flagship phones. Unfortunately the smaller phones tend to be budget phones, which means they lack the always on voice feature.

The prices on flagship phones are usually far past the $400 mark but here's a list of recent Android phones that I should have always on voice feature:

**LG V20** (around $700)

- 5.7" LCD screen
- 4GB RAM
- 3200 mAH battery

**Google Pixel** (around $750)

- 5.0" AMOLED screen
- 4GB RAM
- 2770 mAH battery

[Moto Z Play](https://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-play)/[Moto Z Play Droid](https://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-play-droid) (around $400/450)

- 5.5" AMOLED screen
- 3GB RAM
- 3510 mAH battery

So out of all of these, only the Moto Z Play phones are in your ideal price range.